# Coco annotator: How to import data from other CocoAnnotator instance

Tags: computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

Is there some simple way of importing data from another coco annotator system (just the data and annotations without users).

Answer (score 2):

Coco annotator has an import function. Check the wiki page on the repository.

Export from one and import into the other.